# Not subspace of vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I am working on some example of vector subspace.

I have this:
$\mathbb{R}^2 := \{a\in \mathbb{R}³ ; a = a_1*e^1 + a_2*e^2 + 0*e^3 \}\\$

And I want to prove that 
$\mathbb{R}¹:=\{[x,y]\in\mathbb{R}²;x\in\mathbb{R}^2, y=-x-1\}\\$
is not subspace of first equation.

I have solution from the book, but it is very scarce. This is my translation from german language so it is not perfect.

$u\in\mathbb{R}^1\to -u\in\mathbb{R}^1\to u-u=0\in\mathbb{R}¹\\$
Side comment: I figured this part out. It is the use or rules for determening subspaces.

It mentions also that every zero point of the vector space is also a zero point of the subspace.

Then it says that $0=-1$.

I don't understand how did the author of the book came to the equation that a says that $0=-1\text{ is tauntologie}$. I understand that, because of $0=-1$ the second set is not the subspasce of first vector space. I just dont understand where did he get $0=-1$.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subspace $W$, you must have $0 \in W$. So consider $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$, you have $x=y=0$ so $0 = -(0) - 1$. That is $0 = -1$, a contradiction.